# Python urrlib3 error Unexpected EOF

Tags: python, http

I keep getting the following error intermittently, i'm suspecting a proxy on the network is causing this, since i can run my python script when using a different connection.

I'm using python 2.7 and also using Fiddler to help with the proxy authentication.

> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.bogus.com', port=443): Max
>   retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/oauth2/token (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected
>   EOF')",),))

At the moment I am having some limited success with the following setup, it does fail quite often but it manages to work a few times. I am using a session with the following parameters:

```
def get_session():
    session = requests.Session()
    # limit connection pool and connection numbers
    session.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=5, pool_connections=100, pool_maxsize=100))
    # make sure all connections are closed
    session.headers.update({"Connection": "close"})
    return session
```

Comment: i also have the same issue! Searched a dozens of sites and tried every possible solution, but could'nt work it out. One solution you can do is to use try&catch to pass this error without breaking your further code.

Comment: yes its frustrating i have been dealing with it for the last weeks, trying out different approaches. Thanks good point on the try/catch why didn't i try that. It also hangs for a few minutes before it times out, i could maybe reduce the timeout or have timer.

Comment: just do a time.sleep() of some seconds(i've used 25 sec) in the exception before passing

Comment: do let me know if you find a permanent solution for this